# Where does the initial definition of a process's environment variables come from

Tags: cron, pi

I probably won't use the correct terminology here but here goes. I'm starting a program in tmux at boot time using crontab. Crontab runs a shell script to start tmux and then run the program. Later when I connect to the Pi everything is fine. When I connect to the tmux client though things look very different. In tmux the program is running fine but the environment is different. Up-arrow for example no longer brings up the last command and there are no colors in file displays. I figured out using printenv that the environment variables are completely different between the tmux session and the ssh session. So when tmux is run during boot it receives a completely different subset of environment variables than my ssh session when I subsequently logon.

I notice that if I create another tmux session it has the same environment as the other still running session which suggests maybe that the environment comes from the tmux server.

Can someone help me figure out how I could have tmux receive the appropriate environment variables during boot?

If I boot the os without starting tmux in crontab and then start an ssh session and then run tmux the environment variables are the same in both shells(?).

The SHELL variable in these cases is /bin/bash. In the Crontab-tmux session SHELL=/bin/sh.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected the different shells (/bin/sh vs /bin/bash) had something to do with the problem. I didn't realize I could simply change the shell with a simple command. Turns out all I had to do was type /bin/bash on the command line and everything works normally.

Now I'll check to see if this works in the boot script.